# bigtable vs cassandra vs simpledb vs dynamo vs couchdb vs hypertable vs riak vs hbase, what do they have in common?

Tags: couchdb, cassandra, amazon-simpledb, bigtable, hypertable

Sorry if this question is somewhat subjective. I am new to 'could store', 'distributed store' or some concepts like this. I really wonder what do they have in common and want to get an overview on all of them. What do I need to prepare if I want to write a product similar to this?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189911/non-relational-database-design could help you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [NoSQL Database site](http://nosql-database.org/) summarizes the concept like this:

> Next Generation Databases mostly
>   address some of the points: being
>   non-relational, distributed,
>   open-source and horizontal scalable.
>   The original intention has been modern
>   web-scale databases. The movement
>   began early 2009 and is growing
>   rapidly. Often more characteristics
>   apply as: schema-free, replication
>   support, easy API, eventually
>   consistency, and more. So the
>   misleading term "nosql" (the community
>   now translates it mostly with "not
>   only sql") should be seen as an alias
>   to something like the definition
>   above.

That site also maintains [an archive of articles on NoSQL databases](http://www.slideshare.net/guestdfd1ec/design-patterns-for-distributed-nonrelational-databases).  Most of them seem to focus on particular products but there are some more general overviews.  If you are serious about building your own one then [Design Patterns for Distributed Non-Relational Databases](http://www.slideshare.net/guestdfd1ec/design-patterns-for-distributed-nonrelational-databases) does a good round up of things you need to consider.

Answer (score 13):

Good overview of the nosql world: http://www.vineetgupta.com/2010/01/nosql-databases-part-1-landscape/

Comment: Error 404 - Not Found

Sorry, the page that you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! BTW Google finds many more articles with comparisons.

Comment: Error

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/vineetgupta.com/public/includes/lock.inc).