# CouchDB vs HBase

Tags: couchdb, hbase

Are there any similarities between these two ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the surface, they share many similarities:

- Schema-free data-model
- Distributed design
- Map-Reduce as processing model (as opposed to SQL)

However, the details of how each of those points are implemented are quite different, and share very little similarities. I will lightly go over the points.

Schema-Free Data-Model:

- **CouchDB** is a document store, allowing you to store any document in JSON format.
- **HBase** is a column-oriented store, where you store column values and are able to group those values into a row (very simplistic explanation).

Distributed Design:

- **CouchDB** uses a peer-to-peer design for distributing data.
- **HBase** uses master nodes that dictate where columns and rows are written. (again simplistic explanation).

Map-Reduce:

- **CouchDB** has a built-in mechanism called "views" that allows you to define embedded map-reduce jobs. These "views" generate a "table" containing the output of the map-reduce job, which you can then use just as you would a normal table. Similar to materialized views in relational databases.
- **HBase** does not have a built-in map-reduce mechanism. Rather, you are able to hook up HBase with Hadoop to perform the Map-Reduce jobs. What you do with the result is independent of HBase, you can import the data or move to another database.

I attempted to not go into detail, and hope what I explained is sufficient to give you an understanding.

Kristóf Kovács has created a decent [overview of the features](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis) of these databases plus others in the NoSQL field.

Answer (score 5):

They have nothing in common. 
CouchDB is a database and Hadoop is a distributed processing framework.

You should be comparing CounchDB and Hbase/Hive (which are based on Hadoop) instead.

So I think this older question should get you on the way:
[bigtable vs cassandra vs simpledb vs dynamo vs couchdb vs hypertable vs riak vs hbase, what do they have in common?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437005/bigtable-vs-cassandra-vs-simpledb-vs-dynamo-vs-couchdb-vs-hypertable-vs-riak-vs-h)

Comment: Thanks Niels, but I am looking for a more detailed comparison between these two specifically

Answer (score 2):

This is a good comparison for a lot of NoSQL flavors: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis